# How does the lucky attribute affect IVs during trading?

Tags: pokemon-go

I started playing at launch but dropped off for a while as new features were rolling out. As such, I have a bunch of 2016 Pokémon but no lucky Pokémon, until I did my first trade recently.  Based on how I understand trading these old Pokémon should work, I have a reasonable expectation of getting some lucky Pokémon back as well.

But what I don't completely understand is how a Pokémon being lucky affects their new IV values. Are the new values generated based on a higher stat floor? Do the current IVs prior to the trade and turning lucky play a role? Could a Pokémon with high IVs actually have lower IVs after turning lucky? I essentially just need to understand this system better so I can better target what Pokémon I want in return during trades. What's the current understanding for stat rerolls when a Pokémon being traded turns lucky?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/9dagyk/comment/e5ghdip/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/9dav98/lucky_pokemon_new_minimum_ivs_121212/) Reddit thread there is a IV floor for lucky Pokemon being 12/12/12. This overrules the friendship level IV floor effects and, similar to friendship trades, prior IV doesn't matter.

This gives a strategic advantage to those with less than 10 lucky Pokemon trading July/Aug 2016 Pokemon as they are guaranteed to be lucky and, with the IV floor, have great IVs.

Comment: That's not true, I know that lucky affects the IV floor: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/9dagyk/comment/e5ghdip. I'll admit that I don't understand how friendship level affects this. I also don't know whatever else I don't know.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. According to that, iv floor seems to be the only thing affected by luckiness, overruling friendship effects. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: OK. It's still not clear if a Pokémon with amazing or even perfect IVs could have worse IVs after a trade despite being (un)lucky. I have just anecdotal evidence that Pokémon IVs improve based on trading a hatched Lapras with already really great IVs and now my friend has perfect IVs on it.

Comment: There is simply an IV re-roll with the floor mentioned. The beginning IVs don't matter.

Comment: So a lucky Pokémon can actually have worse stats than before?

Comment: Yes, therefore when trading you should concentrate on the level of the pokemon, level 35 pokemon will stay level 35.

Comment: That's take good to know. What happens if I get Pokémon that's a higher level than I am?

Comment: Level gets reduced to 2+ the receiving trainer level. So you can get as good level pokemon from trades as you are able to catch wild.